# JS, клик вне div

Tags: javascript, html, события, click, focus

Помогите пожалуйста, хочу понять как реализовать клик вне дива. Нужно переводить фокус с видео на страницу когда производится клик вне видео, также обратно. Тут есть хороший пример с английской версии сайта: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893144/javascript-detect-click-event-outside-of-div, но проблема его в том, что див с видео находится в главном контейнере и функция всегда вызывается, так же при клике на видео. Подскажите как реализовать подобное?

Comment: Ну так и фильтруйте события по попаданию в видео

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var specifiedElement = document.getElementById('a');

//I'm using "click" but it works with any event
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var isClickInside = specifiedElement.contains(event.target);

    if (!isClickInside) {
        //the click was outside the specifiedElement, do something
    }
});
```

`getElementById` – здесь указываешь айдишник элемента в твоем случае это видео

```
if (!isClickInside) {
   //  Здесь то, что нужно делать, когда кликнул вне элемента
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, просто и понятно.